# How to update Foreign Key from another Foreign Key reference Models Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I made two models that both have same foreign key reference models (usersold) and (currentuserbid) to User model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL).

I have filled out the data for AuctionBids models.currentuserbid. When I try to reference it and set it to same value in AuctionListing model in view.py it doesn't get saved.

I also tried , listing.sold = User.objects.get(id=listing.bid.currentuserbid.id)

Thank you very much!

```
Models.py

class AuctionListing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.TextField()
    bid = models.ForeignKey(AuctionBids, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="auctionbidding", null=True)
    usersold = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="auctionsold",null=True)

class AuctionBids(models.Model):
    currentBid = models.IntegerField()
    currentuserbid = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="currentuserbid",null=True)
```

```
Views.py

listing = AuctionListing.objects.get(pk=id)
listing.sold = listing.bid.currentuserbid
listing.save()
```

Comment: Did you mean `listing.usersold = listing.bid.currentuserbid`? The field is named "usersold" not "sold"?

Comment: @IainShelvington Oh, Thank you for catching my mistake, your correct. I've should realized that. That answers my question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about the way you referencing to foreign key
in order to get bid related to AuctionListing you can use this:

listing = AuctionListing.objects.get(pk=id)
bid = listing.bid_set
Use this document to understand foreign key referencing in django
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/relations/